# php замена двух букв друг на друга

Tags: php, строки

Здравствуйте, нужен код для следующего дела: надо заменить две разные буквы в слове на них же ( буквы вручную надо вписывать, "м" и "п"), то есть для примера: пишем ПарикМахер получаем МарикПахер.
Очень надеюсь на помощь​.

Comment: Зачем тут регулярное выражение? Читайте http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtr.php

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете воспользоваться функцией [strstr](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtr.php) и передавать в качестве параметра функции массив:

```
$result = strtr('МарикПахер', ['М' => 'П', 'П' => 'М']);
```

Единственная проблема - не учитывается регистр, то есть надо будет при вводе данных собирать массив из значений в нижнем регистре и потом верхнем, с помощью команд `strtolower` и  `strtoupper` это сделать не сложно.

Comment: Результат работы вашего кода: `МарикМахер`

Comment: Действительно, забыл про особенность при множественном замене, тогда остается strstr для решения задачи

Answer (score 1):

Для замены символов можно использовать функцию [`strtr`](http://www.php.su/strtr()):

```
$str = 'ПарикМахер';

echo strtr($str, ["П" => "М", "М" => "П"]);
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в ваш ответ описание кода, чтобы пользователям было легче его понять. Для редактирования ответа, нажмите [Edit]. Так же можете ознакомиться с советами о том, [как написать хороший ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). - [Из очереди проверок](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/148364)

Comment: @Yuri , честно говоря, вы меня удивили - что комментировать всего в двух строках кода?

Comment: Ну понимаете, ваш ответ не удалят. Это просто был совет. Обычно если есть голый код, то его просят комментировать или описать :)

Comment: Ну пример, как комментировать - это второй ответ. )

Comment: @Yuri, благодарю за совет.

Comment: Ребята вот что получилось, всё работает!

Comment: $p = $_POST['pm']; 
if(isset($p)) 
{ 

$p = mb_strtolower($p); 
$out = strtr($p, ["п" => "м", "м" => "п"]); 
echo '<div>'; 
echo $out; 
echo '</div>'; 
}